# Перевод из jquery в js

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Пожалуйста помогите, я себе уже всю голову сломал.

нужно было перевести код с рельс jquery на обычный js. Я уже большую часть перевел, только я уже голову сломал в том как правильно переписать

```
let obj = jQuery("select:visible[id^=ch] option:selected");
```

Как нужно прописать это значение в js чтобы мы получили именно выбранный option, который сейчас есть. Для понимания структуры, так выглядит код:

https://jsfiddle.net/935zp0bn/2/

Comment: document.querySelector

Answer (score -1):

Находим все элементы по селектору, отсеиваем невидимые и возвращаем объект выделенных опций каждого найденного по селектору элемента

```
   let obj = [...document.querySelectorAll("select[id^=ch]")]
        .filter(i => i.offsetWidth && i.offsetHeight)
        .map(i => i.options[i.selectedIndex]);
```

Comment: Это не будет корректно работать в js

Comment: как всегда не заметил что там недопустимые CSS-селекторы